# How to set 'back to top' above footer after scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the code given below for my back to top option

```
          $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
    $("#to-top").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#to-top").fadeOut();
}
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - $("#footer").height()) {
    $('#to-top').css("position","fixed");    //resetting it
    $('#to-top').css("bottom","0"); //resetting it
}
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - $("#footer").height()) {
    $('#to-top').css("position","relative"); // make it related
    $('#to-top').css("bottom","188px"); // 60 px, height of #toTop
}

});


$("#to-top").click(function() {
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
});
```

but it does not work while i scroll down, because my content has the position relative as well as i have a floting div which position is absolute.In above code i need to set the position of my content is absolute.If i do this the two content displace.
here is my html code:

```
<a id="to-top" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:15px;" href="#" title="Back to Top"><img src="../images/BackToTop_icon.jpg"/></a>
```

how can i fixed this problem..

Comment: You need to fill in a value for scrolltop. For example
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#to-top").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#to-top").fadeOut();
}

Comment: `$(this).scrollTop()`... Why checking for this? The value returned is an integer..

Comment: There is no problem with fadeIn or fadeOut but i need to stop the back to top image before footer.thank you

Comment: Do you have a screenshot so I can see how you want it? Because I don't understand the question, and the situation..

Comment: Make a fiddle or snippet reproducing the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now correct and it works....

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#to-top").css("display","none");
      });

   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
        $("#to-top").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#to-top").fadeOut();
    }
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - $("#sc-main-footer").height()) {
        $('#to-top').css("position","fixed");    //resetting it
        $('#to-top').css("bottom","0"); //resetting it
    }
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - $("#sc-main-footer").height()) {
        $('#to-top').css("bottom","188px");

    }

});


$("#to-top").click(function() {
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to animate anything, then `window.scrollTo(0,0)` will do. (x coord, y coord).

If you want to animate it, then this will do: 
`$('body').animate({scrollTop:0},2000);`

no need to create old html hash-anchors (`www.domain.com/index.html#paragraph2`), jQuery does the trick :)